# Converting a query from Sybase IQ to impala

Tags: sql, impala, sap-iq

```
SELECT f.exch 
FROM   ( 
              SELECT 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN sourcedesk IN ('GOBUS_NY', 
                                                'GOBUS_UK', 
                                                'PETRDAES', 
                                                'PEETRAD') THEN clientid 
                            WHEN sourcedesk = 'AESLDN' 
                            AND    clientid != '' THEN clientid 
                            ELSE owner 
                     END                               AS aclient, 
                     clientid                          AS client, 
                     orderid                           AS gaotag, 
                     exchange                          AS exch, 
                     side                              AS side, 
                     securityid                        AS sym, 
                     cumulativequantity*executionprice AS value, 
                     cumulativequantity                AS qdone, 
                     fillid                            AS gaftag, 
                     executionexchangetimestamplcl     AS xstamp, 
                     executionprice                    AS lprice, 
                     executionexchangeid               AS xftag, 
                     serverid                          AS srvid, 
                     reasoncode                        AS rescode, 
                     rootfillid                        AS rgaftag, 
                     miccode                           AS miccode, 
                     mifidtradeflags                   AS mifidtradeflags, 
                     sourcedesk                        AS desk 
              FROM   fillsastextdatestring 
              WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
              AND    exchange = 'VEX' 
              AND    sourceservicename LIKE 'vexprod%' 
              AND    securityid LIKE '%.%' 
              UNION ALL 
              SELECT 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN sourcedesk IN ('GOBUS_NY', 
                                                'GOBUS_UK', 
                                                'PETRDAES', 
                                                'PEETRAD', 
                                                'VEXSVC', 
                                                'LLSOR') THEN clientid 
                            WHEN sourcedesk = 'AESLDN' 
                            AND    clientid != '' THEN clientid 
                            ELSE owner 
                     END                               AS aclient, 
                     clientid                          AS client, 
                     orderid                           AS gaotag, 
                     exchange                          AS exch, 
                     side                              AS side, 
                     securityid                        AS sym, 
                     cumulativequantity*executionprice AS value, 
                     cumulativequantity                AS qdone, 
                     fillid                            AS gaftag, 
                     executionexchangetimestamplcl     AS xstamp, 
                     executionprice                    AS lprice, 
                     executionexchangeid               AS xftag, 
                     serverid                          AS srvid, 
                     reasoncode                        AS rescode, 
                     rootfillid                        AS rgaftag, 
                     miccode                           AS miccode, 
                     mifidtradeflags                   AS mifidtradeflags, 
                     sourcedesk                        AS desk 
              FROM   fillsastextdatestring 
              WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
              AND    sourceservicename IN ('SORUK', 
                                           'PRODSorBkFlr', 
                                           'PRODFixBkFlr', 
                                           'PRODFixBkFlr1', 
                                           'PRODFixBkFlr2', 
                                           'PRODSmgBkFlr', 
                                           'ECGaia2Agora') 
              AND    owner NOT LIKE 'tree%' 
              AND    securityid LIKE '%.%' 
              UNION ALL 
              SELECT 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN sourcedesk IN ('GOBUS_NY', 
                                                'GOBUS_UK', 
                                                'PETRDAES', 
                                                'PEETRAD', 
                                                'VEXSVC', 
                                                'LLSOR') THEN clientid 
                            WHEN sourcedesk = 'AESLDN' 
                            AND    clientid != '' THEN clientid 
                            ELSE owner 
                     END                               AS aclient, 
                     clientid                          AS client, 
                     orderid                           AS gaotag, 
                     exchange                          AS exch, 
                     side                              AS side, 
                     securityid                        AS sym, 
                     cumulativequantity*executionprice AS value, 
                     cumulativequantity                AS qdone, 
                     fillid                            AS gaftag, 
                     executionexchangetimestamplcl     AS xstamp, 
                     executionprice                    AS lprice, 
                     executionexchangeid               AS xftag, 
                     serverid                          AS srvid, 
                     reasoncode                        AS rescode, 
                     rootfillid                        AS rgaftag, 
                     miccode                           AS miccode, 
                     mifidtradeflags                   AS mifidtradeflags, 
                     sourcedesk                        AS desk 
              FROM   fillsastextdatestring 
              WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
              AND    securityid LIKE '%.%' 
              AND    exchange = 'BENCHMKX' 
              AND    sourceservicename LIKE 'BENCHM_%' 
              UNION ALL 
              SELECT 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN sourcedesk IN ('GOBUS_NY', 
                                                'GOBUS_UK', 
                                                'PETRDAES', 
                                                'PEETRAD', 
                                                'VEXSVC', 
                                                'LLSOR') THEN clientid 
                            WHEN sourcedesk = 'AESLDN' 
                            AND    clientid != '' THEN clientid 
                            ELSE owner 
                     END                               AS aclient, 
                     clientid                          AS client, 
                     orderid                           AS gaotag, 
                     exchange                          AS exch, 
                     side                              AS side, 
                     securityid                        AS sym, 
                     cumulativequantity*executionprice AS value, 
                     cumulativequantity                AS qdone, 
                     fillid                            AS gaftag, 
                     executionexchangetimestamplcl     AS xstamp, 
                     executionprice                    AS lprice, 
                     executionexchangeid               AS xftag, 
                     serverid                          AS srvid, 
                     reasoncode                        AS rescode, 
                     rootfillid                        AS rgaftag, 
                     miccode                           AS miccode, 
                     mifidtradeflags                   AS mifidtradeflags, 
                     sourcedesk                        AS desk 
              FROM   fillsastextdatestring 
              WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
              AND    sourceservicename = 'ECGaia2Agora' 
              AND    owner NOT LIKE 'tree%' 
              AND    exchange IN ('BATS', 
                                  'CHIX') 
              AND    reasoncode = 'NT' 
              AND    side = 'B' 
              UNION ALL 
              SELECT 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN sourcedesk IN ('GOBUS_NY', 
                                                'GOBUS_UK', 
                                                'PETRDAES', 
                                                'PEETRAD', 
                                                'VEXSVC', 
                                                'LLSOR') THEN clientid 
                            WHEN sourcedesk = 'AESLDN' 
                            AND    clientid != '' THEN clientid 
                            ELSE owner 
                     END                               AS aclient, 
                     clientid                          AS client, 
                     orderid                           AS gaotag, 
                     exchange                          AS exch, 
                     side                              AS side, 
                     securityid                        AS sym, 
                     cumulativequantity*executionprice AS value, 
                     cumulativequantity                AS qdone, 
                     fillid                            AS gaftag, 
                     executionexchangetimestamplcl     AS xstamp, 
                     executionprice                    AS lprice, 
                     executionexchangeid               AS xftag, 
                     serverid                          AS srvid, 
                     reasoncode                        AS rescode, 
                     rootfillid                        AS rgaftag, 
                     miccode                           AS miccode, 
                     mifidtradeflags                   AS mifidtradeflags, 
                     sourcedesk                        AS desk 
              FROM   fillsastextdatestring 
              WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
              AND    sourceservicename LIKE 'tars_%' ) AS f, 
       ( 
              SELECT orderid             AS gaotag, 
                     serverid            AS srvid, 
                     securityidasentered AS enteredsym, 
                     securityid          AS sym, 
                     rootorderid         AS rgaotag, 
                     timeinforce         AS tif, 
                     settletype          AS settletype, 
                     sourceservicename   AS appl, 
                     account             AS acct 
              FROM   ordersastextdatestring 
              WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
              AND    destinationdesk IN ('BENCHX', 
                                         'VEXSVC', 
                                         'SORMKT', 
                                         'MAIA', 
                                         'LLSOR', 
                                         'TARSSVC')) AS o, 
where  f.gaotag = o.gaotag
```

The above query fails with the following error in impala:

**AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 4:undefined: where f.gaotag = o.gaotag ^ Encountered: WHERE Expected: DEFAULT, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error**

I went through the following cloudera link:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/impala_subqueries.html but could not make this work.

I am new to both Sybase IQ and Imapala.

Comment: at least try format the code in readable way

Comment: @deb . . . Simplify!  Try building the query in Impala piece by piece, column by column, table by table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replace the last query with the below one and try running it -

```
SELECT f.exch 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN sourcedesk IN ( 'GOBUS_NY', 'GOBUS_UK', 'PETRDAES', 
                                      'PEETRAD' ) 
                       THEN 
                 clientid 
                 WHEN sourcedesk = 'AESLDN' 
                      AND clientid != '' THEN clientid 
                 ELSE owner 
               END                                 AS aclient, 
               clientid                            AS client, 
               orderid                             AS gaotag, 
               exchange                            AS exch, 
               side                                AS side, 
               securityid                          AS sym, 
               cumulativequantity * executionprice AS value, 
               cumulativequantity                  AS qdone, 
               fillid                              AS gaftag, 
               executionexchangetimestamplcl       AS xstamp, 
               executionprice                      AS lprice, 
               executionexchangeid                 AS xftag, 
               serverid                            AS srvid, 
               reasoncode                          AS rescode, 
               rootfillid                          AS rgaftag, 
               miccode                             AS miccode, 
               mifidtradeflags                     AS mifidtradeflags, 
               sourcedesk                          AS desk 
        FROM   fillsastextdatestring 
        WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
               AND exchange = 'VEX' 
               AND sourceservicename LIKE 'vexprod%' 
               AND securityid LIKE '%.%' 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN sourcedesk IN ( 'GOBUS_NY', 'GOBUS_UK', 'PETRDAES', 
                                      'PEETRAD', 
                                      'VEXSVC', 'LLSOR' ) THEN clientid 
                 WHEN sourcedesk = 'AESLDN' 
                      AND clientid != '' THEN clientid 
                 ELSE owner 
               END                                 AS aclient, 
               clientid                            AS client, 
               orderid                             AS gaotag, 
               exchange                            AS exch, 
               side                                AS side, 
               securityid                          AS sym, 
               cumulativequantity * executionprice AS value, 
               cumulativequantity                  AS qdone, 
               fillid                              AS gaftag, 
               executionexchangetimestamplcl       AS xstamp, 
               executionprice                      AS lprice, 
               executionexchangeid                 AS xftag, 
               serverid                            AS srvid, 
               reasoncode                          AS rescode, 
               rootfillid                          AS rgaftag, 
               miccode                             AS miccode, 
               mifidtradeflags                     AS mifidtradeflags, 
               sourcedesk                          AS desk 
        FROM   fillsastextdatestring 
        WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
               AND sourceservicename IN ( 'SORUK', 'PRODSorBkFlr', 
                                          'PRODFixBkFlr', 
                                          'PRODFixBkFlr1', 
                                          'PRODFixBkFlr2', 'PRODSmgBkFlr', 
                                          'ECGaia2Agora' ) 
               AND owner NOT LIKE 'tree%' 
               AND securityid LIKE '%.%' 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN sourcedesk IN ( 'GOBUS_NY', 'GOBUS_UK', 'PETRDAES', 
                                      'PEETRAD', 
                                      'VEXSVC', 'LLSOR' ) THEN clientid 
                 WHEN sourcedesk = 'AESLDN' 
                      AND clientid != '' THEN clientid 
                 ELSE owner 
               END                                 AS aclient, 
               clientid                            AS client, 
               orderid                             AS gaotag, 
               exchange                            AS exch, 
               side                                AS side, 
               securityid                          AS sym, 
               cumulativequantity * executionprice AS value, 
               cumulativequantity                  AS qdone, 
               fillid                              AS gaftag, 
               executionexchangetimestamplcl       AS xstamp, 
               executionprice                      AS lprice, 
               executionexchangeid                 AS xftag, 
               serverid                            AS srvid, 
               reasoncode                          AS rescode, 
               rootfillid                          AS rgaftag, 
               miccode                             AS miccode, 
               mifidtradeflags                     AS mifidtradeflags, 
               sourcedesk                          AS desk 
        FROM   fillsastextdatestring 
        WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
               AND securityid LIKE '%.%' 
               AND exchange = 'BENCHMKX' 
               AND sourceservicename LIKE 'BENCHM_%' 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN sourcedesk IN ( 'GOBUS_NY', 'GOBUS_UK', 'PETRDAES', 
                                      'PEETRAD', 
                                      'VEXSVC', 'LLSOR' ) THEN clientid 
                 WHEN sourcedesk = 'AESLDN' 
                      AND clientid != '' THEN clientid 
                 ELSE owner 
               END                                 AS aclient, 
               clientid                            AS client, 
               orderid                             AS gaotag, 
               exchange                            AS exch, 
               side                                AS side, 
               securityid                          AS sym, 
               cumulativequantity * executionprice AS value, 
               cumulativequantity                  AS qdone, 
               fillid                              AS gaftag, 
               executionexchangetimestamplcl       AS xstamp, 
               executionprice                      AS lprice, 
               executionexchangeid                 AS xftag, 
               serverid                            AS srvid, 
               reasoncode                          AS rescode, 
               rootfillid                          AS rgaftag, 
               miccode                             AS miccode, 
               mifidtradeflags                     AS mifidtradeflags, 
               sourcedesk                          AS desk 
        FROM   fillsastextdatestring 
        WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
               AND sourceservicename = 'ECGaia2Agora' 
               AND owner NOT LIKE 'tree%' 
               AND exchange IN ( 'BATS', 'CHIX' ) 
               AND reasoncode = 'NT' 
               AND side = 'B' 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN sourcedesk IN ( 'GOBUS_NY', 'GOBUS_UK', 'PETRDAES', 
                                      'PEETRAD', 
                                      'VEXSVC', 'LLSOR' ) THEN clientid 
                 WHEN sourcedesk = 'AESLDN' 
                      AND clientid != '' THEN clientid 
                 ELSE owner 
               END                                 AS aclient, 
               clientid                            AS client, 
               orderid                             AS gaotag, 
               exchange                            AS exch, 
               side                                AS side, 
               securityid                          AS sym, 
               cumulativequantity * executionprice AS value, 
               cumulativequantity                  AS qdone, 
               fillid                              AS gaftag, 
               executionexchangetimestamplcl       AS xstamp, 
               executionprice                      AS lprice, 
               executionexchangeid                 AS xftag, 
               serverid                            AS srvid, 
               reasoncode                          AS rescode, 
               rootfillid                          AS rgaftag, 
               miccode                             AS miccode, 
               mifidtradeflags                     AS mifidtradeflags, 
               sourcedesk                          AS desk 
        FROM   fillsastextdatestring 
        WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
               AND sourceservicename LIKE 'tars_%') AS f 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT orderid             AS gaotag, 
                          serverid            AS srvid, 
                          securityidasentered AS enteredsym, 
                          securityid          AS sym, 
                          rootorderid         AS rgaotag, 
                          timeinforce         AS tif, 
                          settletype          AS settletype, 
                          sourceservicename   AS appl, 
                          account             AS acct 
                   FROM   ordersastextdatestring 
                   WHERE  agoralocaltradedate = '190205' 
                          AND destinationdesk IN ( 'BENCHX', 'VEXSVC', 'SORMKT', 
                                                   'MAIA' 
                                                   , 
                                                   'LLSOR', 'TARSSVC' )) o 
               ON f.gaotag = o.gaotag;
```

Comment: Can you run each individual query and tell us which particular query is having issue.. take each part of union all and try to fetch the results

Comment: The issue seems to be at the point of inner join or where clause, rest of he query runs fine when run individually.

Comment: Issue was with join syntax which i added, Can you check again now